# Wordpress website loading time

Tags: wordpress

I installed new wordpress . and made some changes in twentyten theme.. only color change.. nothing added extra.

But loading time is too much high. it takes more than 25 second to open website.

Can u tell me why it is happening .

To open website [click here](http://www.knowledgefull.org)

Thanks

Comment: No problems with loading here, loads very quickly, sure it isn't your internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes 2 seconds for me to see your website.

I think you should check your internet connection speed.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out because now it took me to the installation page! 
Sometimes happens to me I forgot a semicolon or a closing tag and tag mess a little bit the loading time. Try also to optimize your DB and add WP-minify plugin and if you have lot of images there's a plugin called smush it

Good luck!